# Difference between installing packages with conda and pip

Tags: python, conda

I'm using conda prompt to install some packages in my conda environment.

The package "openpyxl" was being install with the version 3.0.8 with conda, so I uninstalled it and installed it using pip, which gave the version 3.1.2.

What are the differences between these two commands.

When I don conda list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pip install will (by default) use the packages as available from: https://pypi.org/

Anaconda will instead use: https://anaconda.org

Both are configurable, and you can point them elsewhere if you want.